# Path of Weblogic domain directory in a Java app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

Is there an easy way of reading the directory path of the Weblogic domain the Java application is running in?

I can easily access the name of the server with System.getProperty("weblogic.Name") but I don't know what is the variable that holds the path of the Weblogic domain folder if there is one at all.

I know I could set up a variable like this but I was wondering if there is one already in Weblogic.

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`System.getProperty("weblogic.Name")` will return the WebLogic server's name as it is passed via a JVM argument during startup of the server, from the script startWebLogic.sh or startWebLogic.cmd:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% ...
```

You can add another JVM argument to pass the WebLogic domain, that is available as the environment variable `DOMAIN_HOME`:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Dweblogic.domainDir=%DOMAIN_HOME%...
```

which you can then read using

```
System.getProperty("weblogic.domainDir");
```

You can also read the environment variable `DOMAIN_HOME` directly using [`System.getenv(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String domainDir = System.getenv("DOMAIN_HOME");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the JMX service to get hold of the domain home directory from the 'RuntimeService > DomainConfiguration > RootDirectory'. You can use the following code to get hold of the domain directory from within an app.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
MBeanServer server = (MBeanServer)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime"); 
ObjectName service = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=RuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.RuntimeServiceMBean");
ObjectName domain = (ObjectName)server.getAttribute(service, "DomainConfiguration");
System.out.println(server.getAttribute(domain, "RootDirectory"));
```

For more information you can refer to http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13728/accesswls.htm#JMXCU144